# Convert MongoDB BSON ObjectId (oid) to generated time in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mongodb, bson

I've found this:

function: http://github.com/timburks/NuMongoDB/blob/master/src/bson.c#L128
bytes: http://github.com/timburks/NuMongoDB/blob/master/src/platform_hacks.h#L55
struct: http://github.com/timburks/NuMongoDB/blob/master/src/bson.h#L70

But how exactly would I use this for my iPhone app that gets the oid as a string from the server and want to extract the created_at timestamp? This is what I have so far. It's an Objective-C method, but can I put c code in my Objective-c .m file?

```
- timeFromBsonOid:(NSString *)oid {
    time_t out;
    memcpy(&out, oid, 4);
    return out;
}
```

Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the oid string to NSDate like this:

```
NSString *asd = @"4c8f695bdaf9856dbe000008";
long result;
BOOL success = [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[asd substringToIndex:8]] scanHexLongLong:&result];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:result];
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks! I'll try it out. Anyone know how to do this in c in my Objective-C project? Is that even worth the extra performance gain? Probably not, huh?

Comment: The result variable should be an unsigned long long.

Comment: I've been using a minor variation of this code for almost a year as a category on NSDate. I finally got around to sharing the code on Github. kosii, I've given you credit in the README. For anyone else who needs to do this, you can find the code here: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/NSDate-DateFromBSONObjectID

Comment: yeah, using long instead of unsigned long long will trigger memory related crashes on 32-bit devices

Answer (score 0):

Kossi's answer's a bit out of date. Make sure to use unsigned long long instead as otherwise you may notice odd behavior and crashes on 32bit and 64bit devices.

```
NSString *asd = @"4c8f695bdaf9856dbe000008";
unsigned long long result;
BOOL success = [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[asd substringToIndex:8]] scanHexLongLong:&result];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:result];
```